# How to calculate how many minutes ago a post was created?

Tags: python, flask

Question is asked in title. The problem is that i want my website to be used globally and because there are different timezones i would like to say how many minutes/hours/days/years ago something was posted.

Comment: What kind of infrastructure you are using?

Comment: Just use GMT/UTC for the time format. This will remove any effect of time zones and daylight savings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're creating a site that contains user-generated content, then this is important.

So I do know that Django that there is a timesince filter, timesince.

This can be done through the following code.

```
{{ post.timestamp | timesince }}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Simple and easy. Thank you for replying!

Answer (score 0):

Just convert everything to one time zone when you save the date.

Comment: The problem is that i want to convert it to local users time or just show how many minutes ago it was.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of pytz module for accurate and cross platform timezone calculations. Take a look at this.

https://pypi.org/project/pytz/

Here is what you can do is, at the time of the creation of user's post, use the above module and retrieve the localtime with the timezone details and convert it to UTC and store the same, to retrieve it all you need to do is "depending on the region add or sub the respective number as mentioned in the timezone map.

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/88/World_Time_Zones_Map.png